# Possible to have two views on the same Perforce stream?

Tags: perforce, perforce-stream

I have a project set up in a Perforce depot, with a single mainline stream.

I have some tools (CI, git p4) that can only sync a whole stream at once.

My project has lots of large files that aren't always needed (source art assets in a video game). I would like to allow those tools to only sync some of my depot.

Without streams, I would be able to set up a workspace which only included the parts of the depot I needed. With streams though, it looks like this mapping (the 'stream view') is part of the stream itself, and that if another view is wanted, another stream has to be created, and manually updated with changes from the mainline - which sounds awfully similar to branching, which isn't what I want to do.

What I'd like to know, is if there's some way of accomplishing this - multiple views on the same content - with streams.

Comment: To be crystal clear, I don't want any merging/branching going on here, just separate views, of subsets of the same depot.

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for "virtual" streams. You create two different child streams of the parent stream. Each stream is a virtual stream, and thus allows a different view of the same parent stream.

Comment: Thanks Bryan! That's perfect!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like in Bryan's comment, what you want is virtual streams.

https://www.perforce.com/blog/120221/new-20121-virtual-streams

Comment: Brilliant - this is exactly what I wanted, I just didn't know which words to google for :) Thank you!